# Convert CSV GPS Logs to GPX on Android (GPSBabel on Android)

Tags: convert, csv, software-recommendations, android, gpx

I bought a GPS Logger - a small device that will, while turned on, log the GPS Coordinates to a SD card every second. It has no display and no other UI than 3 buttons and a couple of LEDs. 
The Device will write its log into a CSV files with the coordinates + meta data.

GPSBabel was a great help to get this csv into a GPX XML file very quick and easy.

However, as i will go on a hiking trip and i'd like to see my track while hiking, i would need an app that i could run on my Android phone or tablet (can't carry my linux laptop ;)).

Is there any app that might have this as a secondary feature that is so far at the end of the feature list that Google can't find it?

Answer (score -1):

a colleague of me was so nice and wrote me a little Android App that solves my problem.

May this be helpful for others :)

https://gitlab.com/seanlilmateus/gpx_converter

Answer (score -1):

Check out SWMaps or Locus Maps or Orux Maps for Android they all can view many different file formats (including GPX) and offline raster tiles.

Comment: Thanks for replying! 
I just tried SWMaps and Locus Maps. I couldn't find Orux Maps, but it showed me the Locus Maps. Installing was the only thing i did. Locus presented me a long GDPR text and SWMaps required Audio recording permission to start. It does not work without that permission as it seems. So both the Apps are not fit for the purpose. Also i'm not even sure that they really will do what i want. I don't want to view GPX files i want to convert CSV to GPX. Locus definitely can't import CSV files, i just tried.